# OrientDB Loading Vertex and Edges from CSV

Tags: csv, orientdb

I am trying to create two vertices based on two columns in CSV, SubSystem and UsedBy, and the column in between is the edge (relationship). But everytime i run my script, i only get the vertex under SubSytem and nothing under UsedBy or Dependency. Any help is appreciated, relatively new to OrientDB.

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "CDE-ODS-PROD-VDB-VCDPCDE1-2016-07-18_LVL1.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "row": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "csv": {"seperator":",",
              "columnsOnFirstLine":true} },
    { "vertex": { "class": "Object" } }
  ],
  "command":{
        "command":"create edge ${input.Dependency} from (select from V where Subsystem=${input.Subsystem} to (select from V where UsedBy = ${input.UsedBy})",
        "output":"edge"
        },
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "remote:localhost/test",
        "dbUser":"admin",
        "dbPassword":"admin",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "Object", "extends": "V"},
         {"name": "UsedBy", "extends": "V"},
         {"name": "Dependency", "extends": "E"} ],
"dbAutoCreate":false,
 "indexes": [
         {"class":"Object", "fields":["Subsystem:string"],"type":"NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX" },
                 {"class":"UsedBy","fields":["UsedBy:string"],"type":"NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX" }

       ]
    }
  }
}
```

here's the sample CSV file and the version is 2.2.5

Subsystem,Dependency,Used By,Strength
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.CORE_CONSUMER_DRIVER_PKG.PROCEDURE.PULL_FROM_QUEUE,Code.Method Call,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.CORE_CONSUMER_DRIVER_PKG.PROCEDURE.PROCESS_UNTIL_QUEUE_IS_EMPTY,1
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.FX_ORDER_AMOUNT_TSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.LOAD_RECON_ROW_TO_TARGET,Code.Method Call,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.FX_ORDER_AMOUNT_TSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.RECON_REPAIR_DIFFERENCES,1
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.FX_ORDER_AMOUNT_TSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.UPSERT_ROW,Code.Method Call,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.FX_ORDER_AMOUNT_TSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.LOAD_ROW_TO_TARGET,2
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.UTILITY_PKG.PROCEDURE.RECON_ALL,Code.Method Call,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.UTILITY_PKG.PROCEDURE.RECON_COMPARE,1
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.UTILITY_PKG.PROCEDURE.RECON_ALL,Code.Method Call,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_STG.PACKAGE.UTILITY_PKG.PROCEDURE.RECON_REPAIR,1
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.FOS_TOW.VIEW.FOS_PORTFOLIO_REF,Query Table,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.FOS_TOW.VIEW.FOS_ICR_MONTHLY_ACCRUALS_VW,1
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.FOS_TOW.VIEW.FOS_PORTFOLIO_REF,Query Table,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.FOS_TOW.VIEW.FOS_INVOICE_DETAILS_VW,1
VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.FOS_TOW.VIEW.FOS_PORTFOLIO_REF,Query Table,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.FOS_TOW.VIEW.FOS_PORTFOLIO_EVENTS_VW,1

i think i got the json to work, but now when i am trying to create the edge i get this error

> 2016-07-29 11:06:05:617 WARNI Transformer [csv] returned null, skip rest of pipeline execution [OETLPipeline][1:csv] DEBUG Transformer input: VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CD_DATA.MATERIALIZED VIEW.ORG_PERSON_DTL_MVW,Query Table,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_APP.PACKAGE.RSCH_ORG_HIERARCHY_SSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.GET_ANALYST_DETAIL_BY_NAME,1
>   [1:csv] DEBUG parsing=VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CD_DATA.MATERIALIZED VIEW.ORG_PERSON_DTL_MVW,Query Table,VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_APP.PACKAGE.RSCH_ORG_HIERARCHY_SSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.GET_ANALYST_DETAIL_BY_NAME,1
>   [1:csv] DEBUG document={Subsystem:VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CD_DATA.MATERIALIZED VIEW.ORG_PERSON_DTL_MVW,Dependency:Query Table,UsedBy:VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_APP.PACKAGE.RSCH_ORG_HIERARCHY_SSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.GET_ANALYST_DETAIL_BY_NAME,Strength:1}
>   [1:csv] DEBUG Transformer output: {Subsystem:VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CD_DATA.MATERIALIZED VIEW.ORG_PERSON_DTL_MVW,Dependency:Query Table,UsedBy:VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_APP.PACKAGE.RSCH_ORG_HIERARCHY_SSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.GET_ANALYST_DETAIL_BY_NAME,Strength:1}
>   [1:command] DEBUG Transformer input: {Subsystem:VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CD_DATA.MATERIALIZED VIEW.ORG_PERSON_DTL_MVW,Dependency:Query Table,UsedBy:VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_APP.PACKAGE.RSCH_ORG_HIERARCHY_SSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.GET_ANALYST_DETAIL_BY_NAME,Strength:1}
>   [1:command] DEBUG executing command=create edge Query Table from (select from Object where Subsystem=VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CD_DATA.MATERIALIZED VIEW.ORG_PERSON_DTL_MVW to (select from UsedBy where UsedBy = VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_APP.PACKAGE.RSCH_ORG_HIERARCHY_SSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.GET_ANALYST_DETAIL_BY_NAME)...
>   Error in Pipeline execution: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error parsing query:
>   create edge Query Table from (select from Object where Subsystem=VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CD_DATA.MATERIALIZED VIEW.ORG_PERSON_DTL_MVW to (select from UsedBy where UsedBy = VCDPCDE1.SCHEMA.CDE_APP.PACKAGE.RSCH_ORG_HIERARCHY_SSP_PKG.PROCEDURE.GET_ANALYST_DETAIL_BY_NAME)
>        ^
>   Encountered "  "create "" at line 1, column 1.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       `<SELECT> ...
>       <TRAVERSE> ...
>       <MATCH> ...
>       <INSERT> ...
>       <RETURN> ...
>       <PROFILE> ...
>       <FIND> ...
>       <REBUILD> ...
>       <OPTIMIZE> ...
>       <GRANT> ...
>       <REVOKE> ...
>       <BEGIN> ...
>       <COMMIT> ...
>       <IF> ...
>       <SLEEP> ...
>       <CONSOLE> ...`
>      DB name="test"
>      DB name="test"

Comment: Hi, can you post the csv file, please?

Comment: Which orient version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to create edge connection (`Dependency`) while your are loading vertexes (`Object` and `UsedBy`) in the same ETL process. Because the vertexes creation is still in progress, so it can't find vertexes to connect with an edge. You should separate your `UsedBy` data in a different `csv` file and run it with a second `json` config file containing edge creation (`Object` vertex in this case was created with the first ETL run).

Note: you also have `Used By` in your `csv` instead of `UsedBy`.

Comment: That was what i was thinking, but even if i seperate it out, how can i create Subsystem as its own Vertex and UsedBy as a different vertex. Right now they are all getting created under Object and Subsystem, dependency, UsedBy are becoming properties. I did fix the Used By when i ran it on Linux.

Comment: One csv file should contain only Object and other csv should contain UsedBy and edge creation command.

Comment: So i ended up trying as suggested. And i still only get Vertexes created and no edges being created. One CSV has list of Subsystem which loaded fine. The second one is the same CSV which shows the dependency between Subsystem and UsedBy.

Comment: SO i think i got the json to work, but now when i am trying to create the edge i get this error